# Push value into a secondary array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, constants, push

I am trying to `push` new data in a secondary `array` using `javascript` in `React` but I am unable to do it.

I have my object declared as this:

```
 const {
    id,
    user,
    task
  } = documentTask;

  const {
    time,
    duration,
    sum
  } = task;
```

And then I am trying to `push` a value to the `task` field from another class.

```
  tasksWithOverallValues.push({
    duration: overallSeconds,
    sum: overallPrice
  });
```

`tasksWithOverallValues` is a list of `documentTask's`.

When I am doing what is shown `.push({duration...` then the object becomes undefined. 
My idea was to call :

```
  tasksWithOverallValues.push({
    task.duration: overallSeconds,
    task.sum: overallPrice
  });
```

Because my it is trying to push the values into an unkown list, but I get the following error:

```
'task' is not defined  no-undef
```

After that is done the object becomes undefined and I cannot do anything with it.

So my question is, how can I `push` new values into a secondary list?

Comment: What you mean by "_I cannot call `task.duration/sum`_"? Can you share an example of what you are trying to do and what error you got?

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356679/1823841) here to better understand your issue. You don't need to use large array of objects. use some simple object to reproduce the issue in demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said `tasksWithOverallValues` is a list of `documentTask`s. So if you're pushing something in there, it should be a documentTask, like:

```
tasksWithOverallValues.push({
    id: someId,
    user: someUser,
    task: {
        duration: overallSeconds,
        sum: overallPrice
    }
});
```

Or if you already have or create the task beforehand:

```
newTask = {
    duration: overallSeconds,
    sum: overallPrice
};
// ...
tasksWithOverallValues.push({
    id: someId,
    user: someUser,
    task: newTask
});
```

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I was looking for, thank you,

Comment: One more question. If task has 3 variables `duration, sum, time`. Is there a way to keep the third variable as null so it would not show? In my case the `duration and sum` are changing as they should but third variable under `task` now also tries to change and it gives me unwanted results.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to change duration and sum for a task with a specific id in the array, is that right? In that case, you don't want to push an element, you want to modify an existing one. I'll edit the answer in a minute.

Comment: no what you answered was correct. I want to push it as the last element so it would show the total in the excel that I will export. But the `task` has a third value and since I am pushing the other 2 values of the `task` the third value which is `time` is also shown in excel on the last row.

Comment: Well, you could add `time: null` in the task you're pushing, like `task: {
        duration: overallSeconds,
        sum: overallPrice,
        time: null
    }`, but it's not very clear to me how you are using these objects, and what is going on with the export.

Comment: Yep I think I will have to add something similar `null` or `-` and just show some kind of a string there. Anyways I will figure it out somehow, thank you a lot for your help.